# Ubuntu 20.04 has problems compared with 18.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, vmware, nfs

I've been an Ubuntu user for about a decade.

**I'm writing this post to warn potential users and upgraders to avoid 20.04 for some time.**

Note that a few things are better (for me) in 20.04 vs 18.04 - particularly multi-monitor support using NVIDIA driver.

Up until about September 2020 I was using 18.04.  Unfortunately, some update process trashed my system, so I decided to update to 20.04.

I use Ubuntu in 2 ways:

- As a host computer to control the hardware on my laptop
- As a VMWare guest computer as my main development machine

My guest remains as 18.04, because of the multiple problems I'm having with 20.04.

More about my setup:

1. I have an external backup drive (USB) that it is encrypted with "cryptsetup" then has LVM
   installed on the decrypted disk with multiple logical volumes (file systems).
2. I have a Windows 10 VMWare guest too.
3. I use two 4K monitors each with USB connectivity - one is DisplayPort the other is HDMI.  Including the laptop's screen, that's 3 monitors.
4. I use sound and video in the guests and in the host via BlueTooth, USB, and headphone cable.

All this worked perfectly in 18.04 on the host computer (with a few minor annoyances relating to multi-monitors and NVIDIA).

Here's the list of unresolved problems in 20.04:

1. Sound from a VMWare guest only works via the headphone port.  Even if the host is set to use another sound device, the guests' sound won't go there.
2. The VMWare guests don't connect to sound automatically at all (probably some error).  I have to manually connect sound when I start/resume them.  Sometimes I receive an error about /dev/dsp being in user and ALSA sound cannot be used.
3. Bluetooth sound (e.g. headset) is unusable especially when trying to feed it to and from the VMWare guests.  This is probably an instance of #2.  This means I use my iPad purely for sound in Zoom meetings (I join meetings twice).
4. NFS server exports randomly stop working.  Restarting the NFS services fixes this.
5. Ubuntu randomly decides my external disk logical volumes are "in use" when they are not.  I can only solve this with a reboot.
6. Autofs stops working.  This might be related to #5, as only a reboot fixes it.

I've been sorely tempted to revert my host computer back to 18.04.

However, I generally remain hopeful that some update to 20.04 will resolve these issues.

The one advantage of using 20.04 over 18.04 is built-in support for my Clevo Laptop hardware.

I had to jump through a lot of hoops to get 18.04 working on my hardware.  But, once I did, 18.04 was brilliantly reliable for the 18 months I used it on the host and remains reliable in the guest.

FWIW, I generally wait at least 12 months before using a new Ubuntu release.  The sort of problems I'm having are generally resolved after 12 months so it's worth the wait.

Only 3 months more to wait...(I hope).

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: You are making me think I should stay on Ubuntu 16.04 for three more years.